# Redirection after the login succeeds or fails in loopback framework

Tags: javascript, json, authentication, loopbackjs

I have recently started with loopback framework and made a simple login functionality by creating a 'customer' model inheriting from base 'User' like this:

CUSTOMER.JSON

```
{
    "name": "customer",
    "base": "User",
    "idInjection": true,
    "properties": {
        "email":{
            "type":"string",
            "required":false
        },
        "username":{
            "type":"string",
            "required":false
        }

    },
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {},
    "acls": [],
    "methods": []
}
```

CUSTOMER.JS

```
module.exports = function(customer){

  }
```

I then made a entry in model-config.json like this:

```
"customer": {
        "dataSource": "mango-database",
        "public": true
    }
```

And yes I was able to login and logout easily. I have a login screen with fields username and password. I submit this form to customers/login and as soon as it gets the login, I get a screen:

```
{
id: "lvrTjKBKXCFPTMFej6AyegQUFYe5mSc1BiYbROZwCBM0jqae7kZ7v8ZfGujfDGgy",
ttl: 1209600,
created: "2014-12-07T08:12:17.572Z",
userId: "5483e88b5e9cf2fe0c64dd6c"
}
```

Now I want that instead of this screen, I should be able to redirect user to some other page (dashboard) and if the login fails, it should go back to the login screen.

I googled up a lot on this and all i found was the suggestions to use hooks. But hooks doesn't have such event. Where do I write the redirection functionality? My guess is CUSTOMER.JS

I found the documentation quiet confusing !

Answer (score 3):

Use `context.res` provided in a remote hook. For example:

```
Customer.afterRemote('create', function(context, customer, next) {
  var res = context.res; //this is the same response object you get in Express
  res.send('hello world');
})
```

Basically, you have access to request and response objects, so just respond as you would in Express. See http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html for more info.

Comment: But is that going to maintain my session? Suppose I do res.render('dasbhboard.hbs')

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `maintain your session`. This only has to to with access to the request and response objects. Session management is up to you.